# Background task in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, voip

I have a VOIP application in objective-c

SIP call is working fine when application is in foreground.

My problem is when my app is in background SIP call is not working after 10 minutes after going to background.

I have started a background task in **applicationDidEnterBackground**

```
bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

    // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you

    // stopped or ending the task outright.

    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];

    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

}];



// Start the long-running task and return immediately.

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{



    // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.



    [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];

    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

});
```

In plist file **UIBackgroundModes** is set to **voip**

I am in a patience for it.

Please any body help me. Please.

Comment: Have you followed all the steps here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12

Answer (score 3):

By my understanding the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` method is used for executing a **Finite-Length** Task in the Background. See [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html). And there is no way extend that period of 10 mins which I have discovered.

Since your app classifies as a **background mode** required app, I dont think you will be needing
beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler.

Read "Implementing a VoIP App" section in the above link.It advocates the use of `setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:` method.