# Objective-c long-running background service for bluetooth, when app backgrounded

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, uiapplication, background-service

I can't seem to find the right documentation, tutorial or SO post to point me towards the right implementation so far... even though there are many posts about this topic floating around.

**Problem**

I have an app that connects (pairs) to a BT device I built. What I want, is when the user presses the home button or backgrounds the app I want to send an update through a BT service layer to a BT device on a regular interval. I am doing this now (only fires once) in the `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` methods and it works perfectly. The problem is that I can only perform this once it seems. Any loops, timers, background type services that I start up in these methods, die very soon there after.

**What I need**

Is for the application to keep looking for my BT device in the background and every 10 seconds or so and send an update to the device. I first need to check to make sure the app is still backgrounded, but once I know its in the background I wanna send the update. When the app comes back in focus I can stop the updates to the BT device but its crucial that it sends them when the app is not in focus.

**Research**

I have found these SO posts ([long-running tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11653661/3794876), [background task execution handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155957/background-task-in-objective-c), [using this in an NSTimer loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835806/check-if-ios-app-is-in-background)... but it dies) but they have not helped with implementation at all.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761722/core-bluetooth-performing-long-term-actions-in-the-background?rq=1. Also you can't use NSTimer in background since it works on main thread.

Comment: @ninjaproger how do I get an interval timer or some kind of controlled loop to run in the background and send updates to my bluetooth device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I wrote this post I was far too new to OBJ-C and didn't quite understand the concept of delegate methods with the proper access level to fire in the background (i.e. info.plist access under bluetooth-central).

The end result a month later was to build a peripheral device that could wake up the application in a timed loop via subscribed characteristic updates. Once the app wakes up, you have 10 seconds to handle the event that has just occurred and since I am only saving off a copy of the data that the device posted, all is well.